# How to add a signIn button in a website and update it based on user authentication

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, playframework

I am working on playframework but I believe this question is more about a general topic of web implementation. I am creating a website where I want to put my signin button on the top right corner of my home page and would like to update it based on user  authentication.

**i.e.** if user is logged in there would be `my profile` and `logout` button and if not then there would be only `signin` button. I know how to implement it using different pages that uses different routes, in this case I can load complete page but I don't want to load complete page instead I would like to use popup window for signin/signup and want user to redirect back on the same page after signing in (**click on signin -> signin form as a popup -> submit -> signed in**) url shouldn't be changing in this process. I have seen this type of design in many popular websites but I don't know how to build one.

I did some research and found, we can do this using jquery's ajax call. With the help of ajax call we can request data from server in background (here I will request html) and update my current page DOM. In this case I am supposed to update DOM of my navbar's top right corner so I will request html for that part only but I don't know exactly how to do it? I am new to website designing, would it be a good design or there is other best way to do the same task?

It would be also appreciable if anyone can tell me how should I update link to my related css & js file page by page. I mean if some css file is not being used in a particular page how to remove reference to that and add a new one relevant to that page.

Sorry, If it looks fool of asking such basic questions here but I just want to clear my concept in web-designing and implementation. It would also be helpful if anyone can suggest me a book or link to read about these topics.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, you were asking for help with the DOM -part of the equation?

Here's an example (see the JSFiddle, for the whole thing, as the current code expects the login button to be present at launch):

```
function login (logtype) {
    var insertInput = function (value) {
        document.getElementById('logincontainer').insertBefore(
        document.createElement('input'),
        document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0]);
        var newButton = document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
        newButton.type = 'button';
        newButton.value = value;
        if (value === 'logout') {
            newButton.onclick = function () {login('logout');};
        }
        if (value === 'login') {
            newButton.onclick = function () {login('login');};
        }
        if (value === 'myprofile') {
            newButton.onclick = function () {window.location.href='http://jsfiddle.net/user/b00t/fiddles/';};
        }
    },
    deleteInput = function () {
        document.getElementById('logincontainer').removeChild(document.getElementById('logincontainer').lastChild);
    };
    if (logtype === 'login') {
        var logIn = confirm('Login?');
        if (logIn) {
            insertInput('myprofile');
            insertInput('logout');
            deleteInput();
        }
    }
    else if (logtype === 'logout') {
        var logOut = confirm('Logout?');
        if (logOut) {
            insertInput('login');
            deleteInput();
            deleteInput();
        }
    }
}
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b00t/a3b9dzaw/)**